# Database error trying to insert numbers and letters in to a table but only numbers work

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to change my old script from msql to mysqli or PDO. The script works when I send an Ajax call to the PHP file.
I use:
http://publiadds.com/Villageop/testAjaxCall.php?points=1998a

but when stored the letters are transformed in number and I need to insert letters and numbers on that table.

My code is:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['points'])){

     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks
    $points = htmlentities($_REQUEST['points']);
//    $statement = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +'$points' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);
    $statement = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET user_id = user_id +'$points' WHERE id = 4 ");
    $state = $statement->execute();

    //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `publiadd_registervillageop`.`users` (`user_points`) VALUES ('points');");   

     if($state){    
          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your Points was saved. Congrats!';

     }else{

          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your points. Please try again later.';    
     }    
}else{
     echo 'Your points wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is when I send the Ajax call in insert the data on that table but the data I need to insert is letters and numbers but it seems the script transforms the letters in numbers. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the datatype for user_id field in your DB table?

Comment: You do a prepare, but still interpolate into the query? :/

Comment: user_id = user_id +'$points' ? What you are trying to do?

Comment: the data to insert in this table is example:    7yynf551nabgldi

Comment: but wen i try to insert the letters its like the letters become numbers wen stored in this table

Comment: i have an html5 app it use this script to send to database the user_id

Comment: Tank you very much to show me the error

Comment: so i have remove one of this user_id so it look like user_id = '$points' and now its work tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the MySQL [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
"UPDATE `users` SET user_id = CONCAT('$points', user_id)  WHERE id = 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well After all the error it is in the query
so now i have change

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET user_id = user_id +'$points' WHERE id = 4 ");
```

to

$statement = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET user_id = '$points' WHERE id = 4 ");
Working script